# Global state container as cascading value (blazor wasm)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In blazor wasm (v6), I have an app-wide state container (`AppState.razor`) as a cascading parameter.

The typical code is:

`AppState.razor`

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="this">
  @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {

  [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

  private bool _isFoo;
  public bool IsFoo {
    get {
      return _isFoo;
    }
    set {
      _isFoo = value;
      StateHasChanged();
      //await SomeAsyncMethod();     // <----------
    }
  }

  //...

}
```

`App.razor`

```html
<AppState>
  <Router>
    ...
  </Router>
</AppState>
```

`MyComponent.razor`

```cs
<!--- markup --->

@code {
  [CascadingParameter] public AppState AppState { get; set; }

  //...
}
```

After a component sets the `AppState.IsFoo` property to update the state (and update the UI), I must call an async method (e.g. save to localstorage). But I cannot do that in a sync property setter.

I could change from a cascading parameter to an injectable service, but I prefer not to.

I may need to redesign - what is the typical approach for this use case? (I've seen code with `InvokeAsync(SomeAsyncMethod)` without an `await` but I'm wary of that.)

Comment: Add a method to your parent compoent to set `IsFoo` dont use a setter. The method can be Async if required and can call StatehasChanged. Using a method also makes your component easier to setup for testing if you TDD.

Comment: @BrianParker Yep that's the obvious way. It's just that I've seen this getter/setter pattern for app state containers, so I'm curious if there's some idiomatic design for blazor that I've not seen yet. If not, I'll use an async method as you suggested.

Comment: @Ionix I only use setters like that if I can't avoid it. It obfuscates the purpose of the code.

Comment: @BrianParker Thanks for your help above. I generally agree with your point about setters, but it seems to be the idiomatic way for blazor state management (also shown that way in the docs). I posted a workaround below... What do you think?

Comment: A method would be easier for someone else to understand and simpler to code, making your solution more robust. I can't see a need to avoid using a method. The way you are achieving your result is very similar to how StateHasChanged() works under the hood.

Comment: `I could change from a cascading parameter to an injectable service, but I prefer not to.`   Why not?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Because for something so simple, I see no need for more boilerplate and event subscription and disposal, etc. This is for app-wide config, so a cascading parameter is suitable. For other forms of config and state a service would be appropriate.

Comment: That's strange, because the answer you selected has both event subscription and an implementation of IDisposable.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 No that is hidden away in a one-time class implementation. The consuming components don't need to worry with subscriptions, they just interact with the cascading parameter.

Comment: Discussion on [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/27296), with possible "official" approach sometime in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different solution that I think resolves most of the issues in your implementation.  It loosely based on the way `EditContext` works.

First separate out the data from the component.  Note the `Action` delegate that is raised whenever a parameter change takes place.  This is basically the `StateContainer` in the linked MSDocs article.

```cs
public class SPAStateContext
{
    private bool _darkMode;
    public bool DarkMode
    {
        get => _darkMode;
        set
        {
            if (value != _darkMode)
            {
                _darkMode = value;
                this.NotifyStateChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public Action? StateChanged;

    private void NotifyStateChanged()
        => this.StateChanged?.Invoke();
}
```

Now the State Manager Component.

1. We cascade the `SPAStateContext` not the component itself which is far safer (and cheaper).
2. We register a fire and forget handler on `StateChanged`.  This can be async as the invocation is fire and forget.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

<CascadingValue Value=this.data>
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private readonly SPAStateContext data = new SPAStateContext();

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => data.StateChanged += OnStateChanged;

    private Action? StateChanged;

    // This implements the async void pattern 
    // it should only be used in specific circumstances such as here in a fire and forget event handler
    private async void OnStateChanged()
    {
        // Do your async work
        // In your case do your state management saving
        await SaveStateToLocalStorage();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await LoadStateFromLocalStorage();
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => data.StateChanged -= OnStateChanged;
}
```

Comment: Thanks MrC! I prefer your solution as it's more testable. Just one thing concerns me... If async work performed in the fire-and-forget fails, all I could do is catch the exception and log to console, but I couldn't somehow link it to the UI because that connection would be lost, correct?

Comment: Yes.  Your update transaction has potentially completed before the async background action completes.  You can raise a separate event if the update fails.  Your updater can listen for that.

Comment: Your solution was doing two things I've learnt to avoid.  Cascading a Component and using OnAfterRender for non JS stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Cascading a component: I understand, one should aim for less coupling, and not expose the entire component unnecessarily. Avoiding OnAfterRender for non-js: why?

Comment: Absolutely correct on the component.  `OnAfterRender`  because all too often it's some sort of kludge - often accompanied by a call to `StateHasChanged` to do another circuit.  I've been guilty as charged in the past.  As per a similar conversation in another answer on components, I don't even implement it on my components unless I specifically need it now.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a workaround.

My requirements:

- I wanted a simple state container as advocated by [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#in-memory-state-container-service-server)
- I didn't want the state container as a service (as shown in the docs), because I wanted to avoid the boilerplate of event handlers and disposal in all consuming components
- I wanted the state container as a global cascading parameter, as it's so simple

The trick is to trigger a rerender, and then to perform async work in the `OnAfterRenderAsync` handler.

`AppState.razor`

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="this">
  @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {

  private bool _isDirty;                        // <-----

  [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    if (firstRender) {
      await LoadStateFromLocalStorage();
    }
    if (!firstRender && _isDirty) {             // <-----
      await SaveStateToLocalStorage();
      _isDirty = false;
    }
  }

  private bool _isDarkMode;
  public bool IsDarkMode {
    get {
      return _isDarkMode;
    }
    set {
      if (value == _isDarkMode) return;
      _isDarkMode = value;
      _isDirty = true;                          // <-----
      StateHasChanged();
    }
  }

  //other properties...

  private async Task LoadStateFromLocalStorage() {
    Console.WriteLine("LOADED!");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
  }

  private async Task SaveStateToLocalStorage() {
    Console.WriteLine("SAVED!");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
  }

}
```

The example async code above is for loading / saving to localstorage, but one could do any async work in the same way.

Notes

- It could be that concurrency issues would cause rerenders and async invocations to occur in an unexpected order. But it should be fine for most use cases, and is good enough for me. If you want something more robust with a guaranteed order, then use flux (which is overkill for something so simple).
- This is meant for very simple app-wide stuff. I wouldn't put all my state in there. For most components I'd use other cascading parameters and injectable services.

Comment: See MrC's solution which has less coupling and is more testable.

Comment: The problem with using a global Cascading Parameter is that you have to mess around with Should Render and it can become complicated when you're interacting/actioning with multiple components. One action which updates the cascading parameter will cause a rerender on all nested components if should render is not set to false for that action.

Comment: @sharpc Maybe, depends on the use case. I'm using a cascading parameter to store some app state, and it works well.